# JFace dialog stays open after pressing the OK button

Tags: java, swt

I am working with SWT JFace dialog.

I added a listener to the OK button, I want to display a message box once the user clicks on the OK button.
The problem in this step is that when I once click on the OK button the shell gets disposed. How I can prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will prevent the dialog from beeing closed via the "OK" button. Just don't call `this.close()` in the `okPressed()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    new OptionsDialog(shell).open();

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static class OptionsDialog extends Dialog {

    private Composite composite;

    public OptionsDialog(Shell parentShell)
    {
        super(parentShell);
        setShellStyle(parentShell.getStyle() | SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        setBlockOnOpen(true);
    }

    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
        this.composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);

        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, false);
        layout.marginHeight = 5;
        layout.marginWidth = 10;

        composite.setLayout(layout);

        createContent();

        return composite;
    }

    private void createContent()
    {
        /* add your widgets */
    }

    protected void configureShell(Shell newShell)
    {
        super.configureShell(newShell);
        newShell.setText("Shell name");
    }

    public void okPressed()
    {
        /* DO NOTHING HERE!!! */
        //this.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1205079 Great, have fun with it.